# Google Apps Script: Preview the Email before sent from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there anyway to preview the email before send from google spreadsheet. I study alot of example of sending the email but I could not found any solution of previewing before sending out.

Comment: Are you using HTML format or plain text?

Answer (score 1):

To show a preview before sending, you can use [Ui.prompt()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#prompt(String,String,ButtonSet)) or [Ui.showModalDialog()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)) to provide a pop-up, which you'll fill with the preview of your email.

If you've built an html body for your email, you can put it into the preview using either HtmlService or [UiService.html()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/html).

Answer (score 0):

Write your email on HTML and use the class HtmlService as the example from:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output

but put all your content inside a variable, include a button Accept or Deny before to send your email.

Se the https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/